# Need to upload binary to test in-app purchase?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

Opinion seems to be split on whether an app binary is required to be uploaded to iTunes Connect before a testing an in-app purchase. I've created the app (no binary uploaded yet), created the in-app purchase, enabled by App ID for in-app purchase and marked the purchase "available for sale". I've followed the instructions in the guide as far as I can tell.

However, when I try it on my device I am unable to retrieve the products - SKProductRequest returns my request product as invalid.

Any suggestions what I need to do?

Does the in-app purchase product need to "Developer Approved" for this to work?

Any definitive answer on whether a binary needs to be uploaded? I would like to avoid that if possible but am willing to do it if required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binary does not need to be uploaded.  Source: my current in-development app.

I am getting my test in-app purchases without uploading my binary, and without setting the purchase to be developer approved.  I followed the instruction included in the docs to set it up.

Have you been testing on the device?  in-app purchases do not work in the simulator.  Perhaps if you posted some more info we could help a little bit better.

Comment: Thanks - that sounds promising. Yes, testing on the device. I'm deploying a debug build on the device - do I need a distribution build (not sure if I can get one on the device though)?
Any chance I need to have my bank-account info entered before this works? And did it take a few hours (i'm at ~12h since I set up the in-app purchase) to start showing up? I'm happy to provide more info if you have specific leads.

Comment: You do not need a distribution build, just use a debug build. No bank info needed.  I seem to remember it not taking a few hours, but I could be wrong.

Comment: How about the actual device - did you need to reset anything on there? I signed out of the Store using my retail account (no user signed in). I alternate between invalid product ID and "Cannot Connect to iTunes".

Comment: I did not other than what you had mentioned

Comment: Turns out I need an active paid-apps contract. I was going from a free app to one that has in-app purchases, and you must provide your bank/tax info before these APIs succeed. Undocumented awesomeness from Apple.

Answer (score 4):

Well, actually I just had a similar issue that was solved only AFTER uploading a binary and rejecting it, so I am not sure that the answer above is correct. Would love to hear something from Apple about it as it is the second time this happens to me.

Answer (score 1):

This is my method... I usually get caught because I miss step 3:

**Step 1**
Create your IAP's
(I won't go throught that in detail... unless someone wants me too.)

**Step 2**
Edit In-App Purchases
Select In-App Purchases for review with this app version. The In-App Purchases shown will be ones in the Ready to Submit state.

**Step 3**
Re-generate your dev & dist certificates in apple developer.

**Site 4**
Install the certificates from step 3. and ensure under Xcode's Code Signing you do this:
- Set both debug & release setting to Don't Code Sign 
- Then assign with your new certificates.

**Step 5**
Clean and rebuild in Xcode and your IAP's should sandbox on your test devices.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This question is just a bit dated, but working through the Ray Wenderlich IAP tutorial (found [HERE](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial)) confirms how one goes about testing IAP without uploading a binary.